# Using JavaScript to get JSON response and display on the webpage, testing JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to create a JS app with the following functionality: A button that gets a JSON document and displays that text. I'm going through an Elasticsearch tutorial, and there is indeed valid JSON at the url I provide:

```
{"_index":"planet","_type":"hacker","_id":"xfSJlRT7RtWwdQDPwkIMWg","_version":1,"exists":true, "_source" : {"handle":"mark","hobbies":["rollerblading","hacking","coding"]}}
```

When using the code below...I get an alert of

```
[object Object]
```

instead of an alert with the full JSON. I'm planning to take the steps next of actually selecting part of the JSON, but I'd like to at least see the full document first...

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><title>Demo</title> <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head>

<body>
  <input id="testbutton" type="button" value="Test" />
  <p id="results">results appended here: </p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#testbutton").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:9200/planet/hacker/xfSJlRT7RtWwdQDPwkIMWg',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#results").append('all good');
                alert(data);
            },
             error: function() {
                $("#results").append("error");
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rather than using `alert`, use `console.log`.  It'll make debugging significantly easier for you in the future.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29694300/4768363 similar issue please go through.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `alert(JSON.stringify(data));`

Answer (score 2):

jQuery tries to "best guess" the data format it receives, and parse it for you.

That's exactly what you're seeing. jQuery has already parsed the JSON into an object for you. To see the JSON representation, you can stringify the data again;

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

... or, you can tell jQuery not to parse the response in the first place, passing `dataType: "string"` as one of the options. `data` will then be the JSON representation, and you'll have to `JSON.parse(data)` to turn it into an object.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the JSON converted to a javascript object from which you can access the individual properties using the `.` operator like

```
alert(data._type);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple!

`alert()` calls `.toString()` on the object which returns "[object Object]".

Use `console.log(data)`, right-click and goto the console (or hit F12).

Or just do as the others: `alert(JSON.stringify(data))`;