# How to achieve the same behaviour in Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

```
$usrname = $this->session->userdata('username');
$password = $this->session->userdata('password');

$data = array('userName'=>urlencode($usrname),'password'=>urlencode($password));
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$datanew = "loginemployee=". $data_string;

$method = 'post';
$format = 'application/json';
$this->rest->format($format);
$login_url = $this->login_url;
//print_r($login_url);
//exit;
$result = $this->rest->{$method}($login_url, $datanew);
```

Can anybody please assist me with this. This is actually a PHP script to login into a website, I need to achieve the same on my Cordova app which uses only HTML and JQuery, so please provide me info on how to do this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('form#loginForm').submit(function() { // loginForm is submitted
var username = $('#username').attr('value'); // get username
var password = $('#password').attr('value'); // get password
alert(username);
var UserData= {"userName":username , "password":password};
var jsonString=JSON.stringify(UserData);
var datanew  = "loginemployee=". $jsonString;
if(jsonString)
{
  alert("encoded"+jsonString);
}
if (username && password) { // values are not empty
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http:// i know URL", // URL 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    // send username and password as parameters 
    data: datanew,    // script call was *not* successful
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $('div#loginResult').text("responseText: " +    XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ", textStatus: " + textStatus + ", `enter code here`errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
    $('div#loginResult').addClass("error");
  }, // error 
  // script call was successful 
  // data contains the JSON values returned by the Perl script 
  success: function (data) {
    alert("success");

    if (data.error) { // script returned error
        $('div#loginResult').text("data.error: " + data.error);
        $('div#loginResult').addClass("error");
    } // if
    else { // login was successful
      alert(data);
      console.log(data);
        $('form#loginForm').hide();
       $("#loginResult").append('all good');
      } //else
    } // success
  }); // ajax/ if
} // if
else {
  $('div#loginResult').text("enter username and password");
  $('div#loginResult').addClass("error");
} // else
$('div#loginResult').fadeIn();
return false;
});
});
```

Comment: I don't have any experience in Cordova app. If you are using ajax for a cross domain means it wont support. So if you are using other domain means please check how to overcome that.

Comment: It is not cross domain request, its from same domain.

Comment: ok. what is the output you are getting now? are you getting any reply from the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done some mistakes in code and I listed those thing below.

1. Don't use `$('#username').attr('value')`. Instead of use `$('#username').val()`. Because `$('#username').attr('value')` return the value of the element while the html created. But `$('#username').val()` will return the current value. Same as change `$('#password').attr('value')` to `$('#password').val()`. For more information check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8312886/3049065).
2. Concatenation operator in javascript is `+` not `.`. And also u added a variable like `$jsonString`.
3. In your Server php code, if your using `$_POST['loginemployee']` to retrieve the `post` values means don't use `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`. Because it will use the entire content including key as invalid json like `loginemployee={"userName":"cloud","password":"cloudnine"}`. If you need like that means u need to use `file_get_contents('php://input')` to retrieve the post content. But better don't use `contentType` in ajax. So you can able to easily get the post content using `$_POST['loginemployee']`.
4. And also if the reply is `json` means use `dataType` in ajax, else dont use that. For more information about `contentType` and `dataType` check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18701357/3049065).

So, I updated the code. Check and reply back if there is any issues. Hope it will work as your wish.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form#loginForm').submit(function() { // loginForm is submitted
        var username = $('#username').val(); // get username
        var password = $('#password').val(); // get password
        alert(username);
        var UserData= {"userName":username , "password":password};
        var jsonString=JSON.stringify(UserData);
        var datanew  = "loginemployee="+ jsonString;
        if(jsonString)
        {
            alert("encoded"+jsonString);
        }
        if (username && password) { // values are not empty
            console.log(datanew);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://url_to_post", // URL 
                // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                // If reply is json means uncomment the below line.
                // dataType: "json",
                // send username and password as parameters 
                crossDomain : true,
                data: datanew,    // script call was *not* successful
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('div#loginResult').text("responseText: " +    XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ", textStatus: " + textStatus + ", `enter code here`errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
                    $('div#loginResult').addClass("error");
                }, // error 
                // script call was successful 
                // data contains the JSON values returned by the Perl script 
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success");
                    if (data.error) { // script returned error
                        $('div#loginResult').text("data.error: " + data.error);
                        $('div#loginResult').addClass("error");
                    } // if
                    else { // login was successful
                        console.log(data);
                        $('form#loginForm').hide();
                        $("#loginResult").append('all good');
                    } //else
                } // success
            }); // ajax/ if
        } // if
        else {
            $('div#loginResult').text("enter username and password");
            $('div#loginResult').addClass("error");
        } // else
        $('div#loginResult').fadeIn();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the server is responding for the code ypu hve edited but, the response is NULL,also the response from the server is in Json format only, but when i un comment the Data type it is giving Type Error.

Comment: could you please post the response json content here?